# PHP Code not executing in HTML

Tags: php

```
    <?php if(!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { ?>
    <hr>
            <footer>
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; <a href="<?php echo GetURI(); ?>" target="_blank">Site name</a> <?php echo date('Y') ?></p>
            </footer>
    <?php } ?>
```

This is the code that will not execute and im not sure why all relevant files have been included correctly but the code turns yellow in the code editor when positioned where it is and does not execute `<?php echo GetURI(); ?>` however i have no problem executing this code `<?php echo date('Y') ?>` i was wondering if anyone knows what the problem is i'm pretty new to this, Sorry if it is simple

Comment: Where are you defining `GetURI()`? I don't see it as a PHP function

Comment: Are you trying to `GetURL()`?

Comment: `if(!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) {` might be preventing it. Please post more code so we can see the whole picture.

Comment: GetURI() is a function inside functions.php which is included via require_once method and i dont think its the if(!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { as the echo date('Y') executes

Comment: what does it mean "not executed"? do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke function GetURI() and php knows nothing about it definition. My advice for you is to enable error logging - it can be very useful in finding the problem spots in your application.

In your development environment set php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = -1
log_errors = On
```

But remember to disable it in your production environment:

```
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
```